# Reply to a message sent to a page

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

Do you know how to reply to a message sent to a page?

You can reply to a user's message by issuing an `HTTP POST to /CONVERSATION_ID/messages` with the following parameters.

A conversation `ID` looks like `t_id.216477638451347`

I'm sending in `GET` the accesstoken, I replaced `CONVERSATION_ID` with the `Thread ID`, and i'm sending in `POST` a var called `message`

But it dosn't post, is there an extended permission? I have only `read_page_inbox`

Comment: please do post your php code

Comment: Are you using a page access token?

Comment: I am having the same issue, the message is created, I can get the uuid returned when I submit it, however when I use the uuid to find the msg the "message" field is empty, like my message has been stripped out  of it. I can successfully reply from the Graph API even with the App set to my App, but I am unable to get this to work directly from the App.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I replied with the wrong account!!

The CODE is this:

```
<?php
include("config.php");
post("Test",$at);
$id = "550773858289457";
    $url = "https://graph.facebook.com/$id/messages?access_token=$at";
    $ch = curl_init();
    $attachment =  array('message'   => 'description here'
                    );

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $attachment);
    $result= curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close ($ch);
?>
```

And it replyes:

```
{"id":"302300649895651_312334605558922"}{"error":{"message":"Unsupported post request.","type":"GraphMethodException","code":100}}
```

Thankyou!